# OpenLayers features not aligned

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

I am serving my GeoServer layer (from `sf` workspace provided in GeoServer by deafult) on OpenLayers.

Following is the code for my basemap and layer definition.

```
const layersource = new ol.source.XYZ({
    attributions: ['Powered by Esri',
                   'Source: Esri, DigitalGlobe, GeoEye, Earthstar Geographics, CNES/Airbus DS, USDA, USGS, AeroGRID, IGN, and the GIS User Community'],
    attributionsCollapsible: false,
    url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    maxZoom: 23
  })

  var maplayer =    new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: layersource,
    zIndex: 0
  })

  var view = new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [-103.32989447589996, 44.18118547387081],
    zoom: 7,
  });
  
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [ maplayer]
    target: 'map',
    view: view,
  });


wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: geoserver_ip+ ':'+geoserver_port + "/geoserver/wms",
    imageLoadFunction: tileLoader,
    params: { LAYERS: streams },
    serverType: "geoserver",
}),
name: streams,
});
        
map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

I am building a search functionality to search for layers by their attributes and display them on the map. The queried features are converted to the basemap CRS and displayed on the map. In this case the CRS of my `sf` workspace is in EPSG:26713.

```
fetch(query_url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: MyHeaders,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (json) {

    vectorLayerSource.clear()
    vectorLayerSource.addFeatures(
    new ol.format.GeoJSON({
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:26713',
    featureProjection:'EPSG:4326'
    }).readFeatures(json)
    );

    vectorLayer.set('name','line_layer')
    map.getView().fit(vectorLayerSource.getExtent(),  { duration: 1590, size: map.getSize(), 
    padding: [10, 10, 13, 15], maxZoom:16});

    // https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html
    SearchvectorLayer.setStyle(styleFunction)

        })
```

EPSG:26713 was registered using proj4 library. I was able to query the layer but the projections are off by a small margin. I am unable to comprehend what is causing this.

[image]
*yellow is the query result (fetch call) and blue is the the wmslayer*

What is causing this misalignment? Also, I have to use GeoJSON to load the feature on the map. I would be happy to share more info if required.

Comment: Which one is the correct one?

Comment: Blue colored line (This is served as WMS from geoserver)

Comment: There's obvious offset of the yellow features to the south, north seems to be OK. The only explanation seems to be that the two layers don't have the same/equally defined CRS.

Comment: What approx is the Y difference in EPSG:26713 units?

Comment: X ~= 33 m, Y~= -224 m. Calculated using `map.on('click', function(evt){
    console.log(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate,'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:26713' )) });`

Comment: That's quite a big difference. I though that reason for difference is different datum/ellipsoid in used projections. For example, for coordinate `[-103.32989447589996, 44.18118547387081]` difference between EPSG:26913 (NAD83 / UTM zone 13N) and EPSG:26713 (NAD27 / UTM zone 13N) is `diffX = 0.96`, `diffY = -21.35`. But I still think difference comes from different projection used for the two layers.

Comment: I'll check on the projection issue if any and revert